# How do I render text infront of an SVG image

Tags: html, css, svg

How do I render text infront of an SVG Image? I am trying to do this, it just hides to the back.

My css Looks like this

```
.Default_View_Text___{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 190px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    top:25.05%;
    z-index: -10px;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #1A73E8;
}
```

Please i need to fix this. How can i get the text infront of the SVG

**Edits**

The HTML looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo2 from './logo2.svg';
import clock from './clock.svg';
import msgbox from './msgBox.png'
import bellicon from './bell-icon.png'
import tab from './tab.svg';
import vis from './vis.svg';
import './HomeDashboard.css'

const DashBoard = () => {
    return (
        <div className="BBDashBoard__">
            <div className="DashBoardSideBar__">
            </div>
            <div className="TopBarNav___">
                <img src={logo2} className="betaLogo__" alt="logo" /><span className="NameSpecHolder__"> Welcome, <strong className="DisplayName__">John</strong> &nbsp;<button className="DispAminName__">Admin</button><img src={msgbox} className="MessageAreaBox__" /><img src={bellicon} className="BellIcon__" /></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4 className="MainPageExTap__">Estimates</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4 className="MainPageExTap__2__">Recently added</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4 className="Default_View_Text___">Default View</h4>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
            <div>
                <div className="TableCustomersBleBg__">
                    <img src={tab} className="blueBg__"/>
                </div>
                <div className="TablesCustomerWhiteBg__">
                <img src={vis} className="whiteBg__"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DashBoard;
```

this is what the HTML looks like , the CSS is quite big, had to crop it a little.

Comment: Is there a reason for that quite big negative z-index. And please show us the relevant HTML.

Comment: And why does your z-index have units? It's [supposed to be an integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: @AHaworth pls see edits

Answer (score 0):

changing some values, everything works fine.

Css looks thus

```
Default_View_Text___{

        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 120px;
        top:25.05%;
        z-index: 1;
        font-family: 'Poppins';
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #1A73E8;
    }
```